# how to use group by on complex objects?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am processing a complex object. The object has a list property of type `public List<ExcelDataRow> DataRows`
the ExcelDataRow object has a `public Dictionary<string,string> Cells` property which is a dictionary.

my goal is to use group by or a self join to group the excel data rows based on a value in the cells dictionary.

This is the class structure which holds the excel data:

```
public class ExcelData
{
    public ExcelStatus Status { get; set; }
    public Columns ColumnConfigurations { get; set; }
    public List<string> Headers { get; set; }
    public List<ExcelDataRow> DataRows { get; set; }
    public string SheetName { get; set; }

    public ExcelData()
    {
        Status = new ExcelStatus();
        Headers = new List<string>();
        DataRows = new List<ExcelDataRow>();
    }

    public class ExcelDataRow
    {
        public int RowIndex { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string,string> Cells { get; set; }

        public ExcelDataRow()
        {
            this.Cells = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the example excel sheet which I am processing:

```
Alias List 1    A   Y   N   English
Alias List 1    B   Y   N   English
Alias List 1    C   Y   N   English
Alias List 1    D   Y   N   English
Alias List 2    E   Y   Y   English
Alias List 2    F   Y   N   English
Alias List 2    G   Y   N   English
```

so in the example above I would like to group by the 1st column which is the A column end up with two groups of `Alias List 1` and `Alias List 2`.

I have written this code but I still get the same 7 rows.

```
var rows = sheet.DataRows
    .GroupBy(r => r.Cells
    .Where(c => c.Key.Length == 2 && c.Key.StartsWith("A"))
    .Select(c => c.Value))
    .ToList();
```

my goal is to get two lists of data rows grouped by the first column name if this is achivable using any method please feel free to advise.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're selecting a list of cells rather than a single cell. This would confuse `GroupBy`.

Try this instead:

```
sheet.DataRows.GroupBy(r => r.Cells["A" + r.RowIndex]);
```

Note that using `RowIndex` fixes the bug with rows over 10, where the length would be 3, not 2.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't notice RowIndex property in OP class